# How to make Jenkins CI use Local time instead of UTC on debian squeeze

Tags: time, timezone, jenkins

I have a Jenkins-ci installation on a debian squeeze.

```
Current default time zone: 'America/Toronto'
Local time is now:      Mon Jul  9 16:00:57 EDT 2012.
Universal Time is now:  Mon Jul  9 20:00:57 UTC 2012.
```

In the /etc/default/rcS file i have :

```
UTC=no
```

Unfortunately this is not working, In the system information of jenkins:

```
user.timezone   Etc/UTC
```

I searched for a few hour.. unfortunately could not find a fix any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank for your time

Comment: 6.5 years later, I still can't configure my user profile to set the timezone I want to see displayed.

Comment: If the Jenkins is **inside container**, you can set time-zone with a `TZ` environment variable. This is working great on Openshift: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61524226/658497

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to pass in your required value of user.timezone as a JVM argument when you start Jenkins.  The Java command line will look something like:

```
$JAVA_HOME/java -Duser.timezone="America/Toronto" [other JVM parameters] $JENKINS_HOME/jenkins.jar
```

Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the Debian installation, but the JVM parameters should either be defined in the /etc/init.d/jenkins script or in a properties file that is referenced from that script.

Comment: I must add, Jenkins don't like to TimeTravel to the past : Last Sucess: -322 ms (#30)

Comment: Just to let you know, Once Jenkins is not "In the past" anymore time for last success and last failure have been fix by itself. Also I did not used the /etc/init.d/jenkins script. I start all my services in /etc/init.d/rc.local I just added the value of the timezone in my launch command. Once again thank you

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777111/jenkins-show-wrong-time/15442488  , with answers originally gleaned from https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Change+time+zone

Comment: on centos/rhel, you can set in /etc/sysconfig/jenkins: 
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Duser.timezone=America/New_York"

Comment: I don't belive Debian has set up Time zone properly in `/etc/init.d/rc.local`.  Would probably worked of you have had a Sysv init script to start Jenkins. There are some examples on Jenkins website.

The `UTC=no` in `/etc/default/rcS` has nothing to do with timezone on your machine. It is telling if time stored in hardware clock is the local time or UTC time.  About adjusting the time, use `ntp` or any other NTP-daemon as a client, as it will slowly adjust the time without time travel.

Answer (score 11):

Three years later, I found several gotchas getting this to work.  So, I'll elaborate upon the accepted answer (which is correct) and add a complete answer for CentOS.

---

## Gotcha #1: The Jenkins settings to change

The current Jenkins [documentation on changing time zone](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Change+time+zone) says to define `user.timezone` *or* `org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone`.  But, I have found that **both** are necessary.  The jelly one works for Jenkins proper and *some* plugins, while the user one works for other plugins.

---

## Gotcha #2: The OS settings to update

For CentOS in the Eastern US, edit `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` to:

```
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dorg.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone=America/New_York -Duser.timezone=America/New_York"
JENKINS_ARGS=""
```

If you put these `-D` settings into `JENKINS_ARGS`, it won't work.

---

## Gotcha #3: Restarting

You have to restart from the command line, the entire service.  Simply doing a Jenkins safe restart is *not* sufficient.  So:

```
sudo service jenkins restart
```

When you've done all this, check that *both* time zone settings match in your Jenkins system information panel: http://jenkins.example.com/systemInfo

Comment: This helped when running jenkins in a docker container under CentOS but options not set in /etc/sysconfig/jenkins. The options were passed in docker variable in docker run command and then passed to jenkins start command.

Answer (score 7):

In Ubuntu 14.04, none of the above solutions worked for me, but I ended up running the following command, which pulls up an interface where the timezone can be changed from the default (none selected) to something more specific:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

First, you're prompted to select the continent, (i.e. America, Asia, etc) and then the city, which in my case resulted in "Asia/Kolkata" for the IST timezone in India.

See [UbuntuTime - Using the Command Line](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime#Using_the_Command_Line_.28terminal.29).

In addition, after changing the timezone, I restarted Jenkins:

`sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins stop
sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start`

and then verified that the time was in local IST time. In `http://<yourservername>/systemInfo`, as provided by user bishop, under the System Properties section, for the "user.timezone" property, I now see "Asia/Kolkata" as its value.

Answer (score 3):

If this relates to the execution of jobs based on a cron schedule (ie Build Periodically), you can set you Time Zone in the cron schedule on a per job basis:

```
TZ=Europe/Dublin
0 7 * * 1-5
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Jenkins in Apache Tomcat, add these to <Apache-Tomcat-Dir>/conf/catalina.properties:

```
user.timezone=America/New_York
org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone=America/New_York
```

Both are needed.

Answer (score 0):

For jenkins v2.73.3 on CentOS 7.1 (in docker) we have found you have to both

**1. set the OS timezone** e.g. 'ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Jakarta /etc/localtime' and

**2. under Manage Jenkins set the timezone** e.g. 'Asia/Jakarta'.

After a regular jenkins:xxxx/restart the new timezone is used.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer to cover the situation when **running jenkins in a docker container under CentOS**. In this case options might not be set in /etc/sysconfig/jenkins (depending on your jenkins service start scripts). A jenkins.sh script is used to start the jenkins service. This jenkins.sh script is similar to that used by the jenkins-inside-docker project so this answer is hopefully useful to any jenkins in docker projects deriving from that.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/jenkins.sh

Below we get TZ e.g. Europe/Dublin and pass -e $TZ to docker run so that we can have a script which writes that to /etc/timezone or links /etc/localtime but the important thing is passing these two arguments in JAVA_OPTS: "-Dorg.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone=$TZ -Duser.timezone=$TZ". The jenkins.sh script passes these to the command-line which starts the jenkins process.

On docker host when creating the container example of docker run command:

```
TZFILE=$(readlink -f /etc/localtime)
TZ=$(echo $TZFILE|sed s#.*zoneinfo\/##)
TZARG=" -e $TZ "

ID=$(docker run $TARG \
-d \
--user=jenkins \
--name jenkins-${USER} \
--restart always \
-p $HOST_IP:$JENKINS_PORT:${JENKINS_PORT_INTERNAL} \
-p $HOST_IP:$JENKINS_SLAVE_PORT:50000 \
$TZARG \
--env JAVA_OPTS="-Dhudson.Main.development=true \
    -Dhudson.footerURL=$JENKINS_URL \
    -Dorg.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone=$TZ -Duser.timezone=$TZ \
    -Xms800M -Xmx800M -Xmn400M \
    " \
--env JENKINS_HOME=/var/jenkins_home \
-v $JENKINS_DIR:/var/jenkins_home \
$VARGS \
$ADDITIONALARGS \
$IMAGE \
/bin/tini /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh \
)
echo "INFO: container ID:$ID" |tee JENKINS.CONTAINER.ID
```

Options were passed in docker variable in docker run command and then passed to jenkins start command.